# Separate text and html part from incoming email

Tags: php, html, text, multipart

Is there a way to separate text and html part when any incoming email is received ? I am using PHP.

If the content-type of the incoming email is multipart/alternative

Mail received from Outlook are throwing garbled text when the message they contains get forwarded.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this class before for a support ticket type system and its simple to use and very powerful

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3169.html